# I cant't call method

Tags: objective-c

I have Method in ViewController.h:

```
- (void)setbannerVisible:(short int)vise;
```

And in ViewController.m

```
- (void)setbannerVisible:(short int)vise
{
    if (vise == 1) {
        [_adView setAlpha:1];
        NSLog(@"Show");
    } else {
        [_adView setAlpha:0];
        NSLog(@"Hide");
   }
}
```

But when i write in other class:

```
ViewController *object = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[object setbannerVisible:0];
```

Nothing happens.

And I create adView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _adView.frame = CGRectOffset(_adView.frame, 0, 0);
    [self.view addSubview:_adView];
    _adView.delegate=self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Dude, whoa, first off method names should start with lowercase letters, would not name an instance object, especially when it makes no sense (how about viewController?). Also, why a short int? Looks like you want a BOOL there. Show the declaration in the .h file.

Comment: What do you expect to happen that does not happen?

Comment: Where do you create _adView? There is such a data type bool available with its contants true and false. Or, if you want it more modern, use Boolean with its constants YES and NO. Anyway, that is not your problem though.

Comment: It is common naming methods with lower case first. Again, not really your problem, but helps communicating in forums like SO.

Comment: What frame exactly do you want your _adView to have. If i am not mistaken then you end up with (0, -50, 0, 0). That is a rect of no height and no with which is off the screen (or its superview at least) by 50 px.

Comment: I get the message from the log, but adView not hiding.

Comment: I never used alpha on an AdView. Did you try setHidden instead?

Answer (score 2):

When your app runs this line:

```
ViewController *object = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

a new `ViewController` instance is created. This instance isn't connected to anything and gets destroyed a moment later after you have called `BannerVisible:` on it.

You need to change your code so it gets the existing instance of `ViewController` that actually has a view on screen and call methods on that instance. How you do that depends on where this code is and how your instance of `ViewController` was created and its view shown.

Aside: method names should start with a lower case letter (`bannerVisible:`) and should be named to describe what they do (`setBannerVisibility:`).

Comment: Ah, Wayne is right. In the other class you cannot fetch this very ViewController by allocating a new one. You will somehow maintain a reference to it and store the original ViewController object in it. For other reasons I don't like having a number of ADViews in my apps. (I think it is not good if some of them are covered and only one is visible.) For the iAdView - and only for this view - I use a singleton pattern with lazy instanciation. This singleton is then shared by all view controllers that display an ad. It has to be added as sub view each time when the view using it appears.

Comment: I do not quite understand how to do it.

Comment: You need to say how the instance of `ViewController` that is on screen is created and shown...